# Pun with "effervescent" and "fiddlesticks"

Tags: puns

I read a pun in a children's joke book "Effervescent enough covers on your bed, your fiddlestick out." I know that "fiddlestick out" is "feet will stick out", but what is the "effervescent" punning on?

Comment: This book is obviously only suitable for groan-ups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Effervescent=If there isn't.

Which should be: if there aren't.